# Python List Filtering

Tags: python

I have a data in list

```
PRODUCT = [
{
    "type": "PLAN A",
    "detail":  "ABC",
    "plans": [
        {
            "name": 'Monthly',
            "id": "",
        },
        {
            "name": 'Annually',
            "id": "",
        }
    ],
    }, {
        "type": 'PLAN B',
        "detail": 'XYZ',
        "plans": [{
            "name": 'Tri-Month',
            "id": "",
            },
        ],
 }]
```

I want to loop or iterate over this array and want to update id for example when in plans name is Monthly I want the id to be "abcxyz" when name is Annually I want the id to be "dvgssd" when the name is Tri-Month I want the id to be "abc123.

This is the initial list it has more data in it. I have tried multiple ways to achieve it but I get error.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: Can you please share your models?

Comment: @ruddra I think it is a python question.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre] of what you have tried and the full traceback of the error you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a nested loop problem. The first thing you need to understand is there will be 2 different loops that will be used.

1. For the product array.
2. For the plans array.

In the first loop, you will get an object from the plans array, and in the second loop, you will set the ids.

Below is the code to help you understand.

```
for iterator in PRODUCT:
for plan in iterator["plans"]:
    if plan["name"] == "Monthly":
        plan["id"] = "abcxyz"
    if plan["name"] == "Annually":
        plan["id"] = "dvgssd"
    if plan["name"] == "Tri-Month":
        plan["id"] = "abc123"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over elements and compare

```
PRODUCT = [
{
    "type": "PLAN A",
    "detail":  "ABC",
    "plans": [
        {
            "name": 'Monthly',
            "id": "",
        },
        {
            "name": 'Annually',
            "id": "",
        }
    ],
    }, {
        "type": 'PLAN B',
        "detail": 'XYZ',
        "plans": [{
            "name": 'Tri-Month',
            "id": "",
            },
        ],
 }]
for obj in PRODUCT:
    plans_list = obj['plans']
    for plan in plans_list:
        if plan['name'] == 'Monthly':
            plan['id'] = 'abcxyz'
        elif plan['name'] == 'Annually':
            plan['id'] = 'dvgssd'
        elif plan['name'] == 'Tri-Month':
            plan['id'] = 'abc123'

print(PRODUCT)
```

output

```
[{'type': 'PLAN A', 'detail': 'ABC', 'plans': [{'name': 'Monthly', 'id': 'abcxyz'}, {'name': 'Annually', 'id': 'dvgssd'}]}, {'type': 'PLAN B', 'detail': 'XYZ', 'plans': [{'name': 'Tri-Month', 'id': 'abc123'}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate through the dictionary and change items if the conditions are met:

```py
def UpdateProperty(dict, id, value):
    dict[id] = value


for item in PRODUCT:
    for plan in item["plans"]:
        if plan['name'] == 'Monthly':
            UpdateProperty(plan, "id", "abcxyz")
        elif plan['name'] == 'Annually':
            UpdateProperty(plan, "id", "dvgssd")
        elif plan['name'] == 'Tri-Month':
            UpdateProperty(plan, "id", "abc123")

print(PRODUCT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in PRODUCT:
    #PRODUCT is a list of dicts
    #i is a dict
    for j in i["plans"]:
        #i["plans"] is a list of dicts
        #j is a dict
        if j["name"] == "Monthly":
            j["id"] = "abcxyz"
        if j["name"] == "Annually":
            j["id"] = "dvgssd"
        if j["name"] == "Tri-Month":
            j["id"] = "abc123"
```